# Report on custom parameters without forking Locust

Tags: python, monkeypatching, locust

I'm measuring performance of various components of my app and I'd like to get some statistics using [Locust](http://locust.io/) load testing framework. Currently, there's a way to measure average response time using a [built-in locust method](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/47abba7990d6792e057a18942cadffa11fd4d064/locust/stats.py#L197).

Is it possible to get statistics on a *custom* parameter (which is a part of server response) and add it to reports without forking Locust? Perhaps some monkey-patching options are available?